# angular-material holy grail flexbox layout

Tags: angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I am using angular-material webkit and I have issue with height of the container that is always setting depending on the device. The problem I'm having is with child elements 'leaving' middle container and rendering on the footer area. On the image, number 1 shows situation when content of the green area is small enough to fit device height. Number 2 shows my problem and 3 is my ideal layout:
[image: Problem and goal]

My layout looks like this:

```
<body layout="column">
  <div> header </div>
  <div layout="row" flex">
    <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="true" flex="20"></md-sidenav>
    <div layout="column" flex ui-view></div>
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-right" md-is-locked-open="true" flex="20"></md-sidenav>
  </div>
  <div class=footer"></div>
</body>
```

I can't find solution on the angular-material docs - maybe I don't get some of the ideas but it's the second day I am trying to implement that layout and I'm still failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the best you can do with flex - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/KgWJrZ)

Markup

```
<div id="all" ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout="column" flex>
  <div style="background:red; height:100px"></div>
  <div layout="row" flex="90">
    <div style="background:blue" flex="10"></div>
    <div layout="column" flex="80">
      <div >
          <!-- content -->
      </div>
      <div style="background:yellow; height:100px"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="background:blue" flex="10"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for help! unfortunately this is not what I wanted to do. I don't want content to overflow, I want that container to get a bigger height so that footer will be below content and navbars. I don't want fixed footer or inner scroll in the content. To be 100% clear - in your codepen, when you remove overflow, footer is on the middle - I want it at the bottom end

Comment: @KonradJanczyk - See update. I think you will have to define the heights specifically for the header and footer but that's not a problem as you probably would want them to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for that! thought I could do this in more "cleaner" way but this should do

Comment: @KonradJanczyk Yes, I know what you mean, but there doesn't seem to be a way of defining the heights of the header and footer with flex, unless the height of the page is controlled by flex.